# Getter for Object accessor

Tags: javascript

I need to cath dynamic object accessor and return object with observe method.

Example:

```
var storage = {};

storage.foo.foo2.$observe(function(value){
    console.log('value:', value);
});

storage.foo.foo2.$set('some value');
```

Accesor key may be variable, such as 'storage.user.name' or 'storage.book.owners'. And nesting depth may be variable. Instead of creating a value in the object it should create an object with methods $observe and $set and hidden variable for store the current values.

It's possible?

Comment: I'm abstaining on the vote to reopen or leave closed, but my advice is to try to be clearer about what kind of result you're looking for, and how the results you're getting differ from that goal. *Examples* would be very valuable in helping readers understand what you're driving at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that, if you know the properties to be watched in advance, and if the objects that they belong to already exist:

```
Object.defineProperty(storage.foo, 'foo2', {
    get: function() { return this._value; },
    set: function(v) { console.log(v); this._value = v; }
});
```

Then

```
storage.foo.foo2 = 'some value';
```

will trigger the setter and the console message, and

```
storage.foo.foo2
```

will retrieve the set value via the getter.

If you *don't* know the name of the property, and want to watch any arbitrary property or something like that, you'll have to wait for ES6 proxies, or you can try the FF implementation described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy.

Comment: I don't know accesor. It can be 'storage.user.name' or 'storage.books.list'.

Comment: Then you can't do it, unless you want to resort to something like `get(storage.user 'name')`.